# How to make a scale slider that changes both x and y scales by same value

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to make a slider that changes x and y scales of a game object by the same value. In other words, always makes sure that the x and y scale are the same.
I know this should be done with an editor but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Create a gameobject slider for each axis, and set the x and y of the game object to be equal to the value on the slider in update(), or some derivative of that value. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-slider